# Change server in all URLs

Tags: paw-app

Using PAW and I have setup a bunch of test URLs for my API server. No I want to repeat all those URLs on my dev and staging servers.

Is it possible to do a search and replace on the server domain name to recreate the same tests for each server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way yet in Paw to edit requests in batch.

The recommended way for fields that are likely to change (e.g. server hostname / base URL) is to set them in environment variables. See this documentation article: https://paw.cloud/docs/environments/environments-reusable-presets

*Note:* batch editing is for sure something that will come in future versions.